# Rails 3 - Bind Pre-AJAX Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, event-handling, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently trying to use button_to to trigger an update to a record.  Since the AJAX request is taking some time, I'm going to simulate the UI effects of the request by updating the UI prior to the request being sent.  Following [this post](http://www.dixis.com/?p=326) that performs something similar for link_to.

In my view I have:

```
button_to "Submit", my_class_path, :remote => true, :class => "my_class", :method => :get
```

In application.js I have the following:

```
jQuery(function($) { 
  $("input.my_class").bind("ajax:loading",  function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
  });
});
```

The event is either not being fired or I'm not binding to it correctly.  How do I handle the pre-AJAX request from button_to?

And as an aside, is there a good way of seeing javascript events as they're fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that `button_to` creates something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/some_action" data-remote="true" class="button_to">
<div>
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
    <input class="my_class" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="asdfasdfasdfsafasdfasdfas=">
</div>
</form>
```

But according to [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js), it looks like the ajax request is being bound to the containing form:

```
$('form[data-remote]').live('submit', function (e) {
    $(this).callRemote();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So in essense, the input button is only submitting the form, which the rails.js code captures and uses to do the ajax call. This probably means that you have to bind directly to the button's form. Something like this:

```
$("input.my_class").parents('form[data-remote]').bind("ajax:loading",  function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
```